# How to animate geometry/particles with attractor

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

[image: stills of an animation with cloner attractor]

I recently switched from C4D to Blender :-) Recently I made an animated graphics where dots was animated from one side to the other while changing color. At the same time ALL dots were all animated - so it looked a little like swirming bees. In other words, the whole graphic was very much *alive*.

How would you re-create that in Blender?

Any help would be appreciated. Best regards

Comment: I think you'll need to dive into Geometry Nodes in Blender to do that which will be a bit of a steep learning process for you if you've not used Blender much! There are a couple of recent YT tutorials from HEY Pictures [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5BQ-5Pb9mI) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO8-WCRJ7Pg) which partially do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. Have a nice day :-)